# Link to webform submission

Tags: views, civicrm, webforms

I have Drupal civiCRM installed. I am using webforms to create contact in civiCRM.

To display these contacts I am using civiCRM views, which gives me civiCRM contact details properly but I am not able to link these records to drupal webform submission.

I am listing civiCRM contacts firstname lastname through views. Now needs to link it to its submission view page

eg: node/2/submission/4

node/[webform-id]/submission/[sibmission-id]

Answer (score 0):

In view webform have option Link to Webform submission. I am not sure it will help for you, but hope this will help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIqZq.png)

Comment: Where is this option? In webform settings? I am not able to find it